# How do I implement a more complex filter?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to query a subset of users based on certain conditions. Filtering by most conditions is relatively straightforward, but some are a bit more complex. For example, here is a function that I'm trying to incorporate into a query filter:

```
def prefs_are_none(profile):
    none = True
    if profile.get_faves() or profile.get_choices():
        none = False
    return none
```

I'm not sure how to add that functionality into this query:

```
user_list = Profile.objects.annotate(
                        distance_away=Distance(
                            'last_location', current_user.last_location
                        )
                    ).filter(last_location__distance_lte=(
                        current_user.last_location, D(km=200)
                    ), public=True, # additional filters would ideally go here)
```

Here's the model for the `Profile` which clears up certain the methods used above(get_faves(), get_choices()):

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    fave1 = models.CharField(max_length=54, blank=True, null=True,
                              verbose_name='Learn A')
    fave2 = models.CharField(max_length=54, blank=True, null=True,
                              verbose_name='Learn B')
    choice1 = models.CharField(max_length=54, blank=True, null=True,
                              verbose_name='Teach A')
    choice2 = models.CharField(max_length=54, blank=True, null=True,
                              verbose_name='Teach B')
    public = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Public')

    last_location = models.PointField(null=True)

    objects = ProfileManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def get_faves(self):
        list_of_faves = [self.fave1, self.fave2]
        return [field for field in list_of_faves if field]

    def get_choices(self):
        list_of_choices = [self.choice1, self.choice2]
        return [field for field in list_of_choices if field]
```

So essentially in the query I'm trying to check, through the `get_faves()` and `get_choices()` functions, that a profile does not have either empty--this is what's currently happening in the `prefs_are_none()` function.
How would I go about incorporating all of that functionality into a query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement `or` condition in queryset. You can do this with [`Q objects`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects):

```
from django.db.models import Q
Profile.objects.filter(
      Q(fave1__isnull=False) | Q(fave2__isnull=False),
      Q(choice1__isnull=False) | Q(choice1__isnull=False),
      last_location__distance_lte=(current_user.last_location, D(km=200)),
      public=True
)
```

In this example `Q` objects joined with `|` will add `or` conditions to the query.